# How to disable i18n RTL/LTR for a single element on a screen in react native?

Tags: reactjs, native

I have this "verification code input field". When the language is set to Arabic then the direction is RTL, but I need to enter the code from left to right (LTR).
If I forcefully set it to LTR, I have to reload the app again to get it working.

[(Here is the image of InputField)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4D8F.png)

```
  <CodeInput
        style={i18n.isRTL ? styles.VerCode2 : styles.VerCode1}
        compareWithCode="AsDW2"
        activeColor="rgba(49, 180, 4, 1)"
        inactiveColor="rgba(49, 180, 4, 1.3)"
        autoFocus={false}
        ignoreCase={true}
        inputPosition="center"
        codeLength={6}
        size={45}
        containerStyle={{ marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 12 }}
        codeInputStyle={{ borderWidth: 1.5 }}
      />
```

So,  I want to do (but don't have any idea) conditional styling for this element.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved because I found a component that provides the ability to override the RTL/LTR.
[Here's the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-inputs/v/3.3.1) to the verification code input field, that provides this RTL/LTR compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You coould add "dir" attribute manually to set always ltr:

PS - also you could set "auto" for autodetection